# How to target child elements of a div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a `div` box and it has child elements like `h3`, button etc.

I would like to do something onclick of `div` but also onclick of its **child elements**. How could I do that? I have tried everything and I can't figure it out..

Exp: http://plnkr.co/edit/nYGldAZMcOC2SG1bddpq?p=preview

In exp above: If you click on `h3`, `h4` or the button it won't do something but only on `div` area itself..

I have tried something like:

```
scope.targetEl = document.getElementById('myDiv');
scope.childEl = document.getElementById('myDiv').getElementsByTagName( '*');

//and checking
if(e.target === scope.targetEl || e.target === scope.childEl){
   alert('in box');
}
```

but that's not working..

Any tips?

Comment: Why do you want to click on the child elements?

Comment: If you want the alert to show anytime you click inside the div and all its child's elements, just remove the if condition and it works. If you want each child to have its own functionality, you could use ng-click

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're checking the target element in this line:

```
if(e.target === scope.targetEl){
```

The target element is changing whenever you click the h elements inside the div. I forked your plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KAqlHJFwPUpJxwUqJBB4?p=preview) and you can see the alert fires when you click on the h elements.

Answer (score 0):

By default, events will bubble up from the deepest element to the highest element. 
Look at this page for a nice article about event bubbling: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

If you want to capture the events from the highest to the deepest element, you need event capturing. As stated on the link above, the only way to do is is using the `addEventListener` method with the last argument set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The childNodes property returns a collection of a node's child nodes, as a NodeList object.
The nodes in the collection are sorted as they appear in the source code and can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.Change the js file as follows-

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('drctv', function(){
  return{
    template:'<div id="myDiv">' +
    '<h3>txt1</h3>' +
    '<h4>txt1</h4>' +
    '<button>button</button>' +
    '</div>',
    link:function(scope,element){
      element.on('click', function(e){
        scope.targetEl = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        var c = document.getElementById('myDiv').childNodes;
        for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if(e.target == c[i]){
          alert('child element');
        }
    }

        if(e.target === scope.targetEl ){
          alert('in box');
        }

      });  
    }
  };
});
```